# ¿Por qué decimos "No 'se' lo digas a Lola" y no "No lo digas a Lola"?

Tags: conjugación, imperativo

No entiendo el siguiente imperativo:

> No **se** lo digas a Lola.

¿Por qué hay 'se' antes de *digas*?

¿No podria ser así?

> No lo digas a Lola

Answer (score 1):

Ambas son correctas. El *se* es aloforma del pronombre átono indirecto *le*. Ya que mencionamos explícitamente el complemento indirecto, no es obligatorio su uso, pero la coaparición del complemento con su respectivo pronombre átono es perfectamente válida, e incluso obligatoria si el complemento es otro pronombre (no se puede decir *no lo digas a **ella***, solo *no se lo digas a ella* o *no se lo digas* a secas)

Comment: En Colombia es más común escuchar decir "No **le** digas a Lola"

Comment: @DGaleano pero qué le dices a ella?

Comment: Lo que te acabé de decir o lo que te voy a decir a continuación. Ej. "Ella me gusta, pero no le digas a Lola" "No le digas a Lola que vamos a salir a comer".

Comment: @guifa Ambas formas son correctas y suenan bien aquí también. En la primera oración que propuso DGaleano, el CD está implícito o tácito (*que ella me gusta*). "se lo/la" será más conveniente cuando haya un sustantivo que sea reemplazado por "lo/la", por ejemplo: Encontré la dirección, pero no se la voy a decir a Lola. (Si sólo dijera: No le voy a decir a Lola, se entendería que no le voy a decir que encontré la dirección. En cambio, al decir "no se la voy a decir", "la" se refiere a "la dirección").

Comment: "se lo" puede ser ambiguo cuando hay un sustantivo masculino: Recordé el nombre, pero no se lo voy a decir a Lola (¿el nombre o que lo recordé?)

Answer (score -1):

Eso no es gramaticalmaente correcta pero piensa en la así:

- Le lo digo a Lola

Ésta sería la manera natural (mentalmente) de que alguien entendiera.

Pero, hay reglas gramaticales.  No es correcta poner:

- Le lo
- Le la
- Lo Lo
- Lo la

Éstas son confusas.  Imagínate como sonaría y como difícil sería oírlas, más decirlas.  Para arreglarlo hay que utilizar "se".  Entonces sólo hay dos opciones.

- Se lo
- Se la

Comment: Me gusta tu idea, de ir paso por paso, pero tu respuesta tiene muchos errores.  ¿Qué tal un poco de *proofreading*?